# How to work with SOAP UI calls using Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, xml, python-requests

I have the following a raw request from SOAP UI. How can I convert it to Python's request?

```
POST https://data.egov.kz/proxy2/culs_payments?token=50a3f6ca0f824f9e97938295fbc7768f HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 273
Host: data.egov.kz
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<sign:Request xmlns:sign="http://xmlns.kztc-cits/sign" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sign:IIN_BIN>090740002542</sign:IIN_BIN>
</sign:Request>
```

I have tried:

```
import requests

url = "https://data.egov.kz/proxy2/culs_payments?token=50a3f6ca0f824f9e97938295fbc7768f"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
body = """<sign:Request xmlns:sign="http://xmlns.kztc-cits/sign" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sign:IIN_BIN>010540001007</sign:IIN_BIN>
</sign:Request>"""
print(body)
response = requests.post(url,data=body, headers = headers, verify = False)
print (response.content)
```

and I am getting Not found error

Comment: Hello. The `data` for a `post` requests takes in a `dict` and not a `string`. Can you tell what exactly is being posted?

Comment: @Mooncrater How can I see that?

Comment: @Mooncrater the first code is raw from SOAP UI.

Comment: I haven't used SOAP UI though. Normally, whenever you `post` something, a JSON object is sent. A string can be sent, but still it should have a name. Even the line `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}` says the exact same thing. Can you try to dig deep into what exactly is going under the hood?

Comment: @Mooncrater How can I make a body dict from body str?

Comment: `zeep` is a python library to handle `soap` requests. I would recommend that instead.